# How to compute the limit of a subdivided rotation applied to itself n times?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, rotation

I have the following function:

```
f[n_, angle_, axis_] := Simplify[RotationMatrix[angle/n, axis]^n];
```

where n is a positive integer, angle is real and axis is a 3d real vector.

So the idea is that a specific rotation, given by axis and angle, is subdivided into n steps and is repeatedly applied onto itself n times.

This should approach some limit as n->+Inf.

Trying to compute the limit I did:

```
Simplify[Limit[f[n, a, {x, y, z}], n -> Infinity, 
  Assumptions -> Element[n, PositiveIntegers]]]
```

But mathematica just gives me:

```
Limit::alimv: Warning: Assumptions that involve the limit variable are ignored.
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

How can I get the proper limit function ?

Comment: Have you looked at the function RotationMatrix? That might be a good start.

Comment: that part I found and solved. but that's about it. ;)

Comment: Then please show your progress.

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! I don't quite understand...do you really mean `f(x/N)` there? Isn't `f` defined on integers? `x/N` seems to approach 0 as `N` goes to infinity.

Comment: Also, I'm not totally sure you need recursion here—isn't `f(n)` simply the matrix `RotZ(angleZ/N) * RotY(angleY/N)` to the `n`th power, or is there some subtlety here about the axes changing, maybe?

Comment: I think you are correct. It should be equivalent to the n'th power. I'll simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr1 = Simplify[
   RotationMatrix[angle/n, {a, b, c}], {angle \[Element] Reals, 
    n \[Element] Integers, a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, 
    c \[Element] Reals}];
expr2 = Simplify[
   MatrixPower[expr1, n], {angle \[Element] Reals, 
    n \[Element] Integers, a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, 
    c \[Element] Reals}];
expr3 = Limit[expr2, n -> Infinity];
expr4 = Simplify[
  expr3 - (expr1 /. {n -> 1}), {angle \[Element] Reals, 
   n \[Element] Integers, a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, 
   c \[Element] Reals}]
```

In `expr1`, we assume an arbitrary axis of rotation, `{a, b, c}` with real components. Set up the `RotationMatrix` for `angle/n` as our general case. Use `Simplify` to ensure that it remains a manageable expression.

In `expr2`, we use `MatrixPower` to raise the result of `expr1` to the n-th power and `Simplify` again with the same assumptions to ensure the expression remains manageable.

In `expr3`, take the `Limit` as `n -> Infinity`. This expression is the one you've stated that you're looking for, but it is also equivalent to `expr1 /. {n -> 1}`, which is proven by evaluating `expr4` and finding that it equals `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}` after simplification.

Comment: cool. this seems to work. however i got a follow up question stated in a new thread. maybe you can help there as well: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242091/simplify-not-considering-all-assumptions-properly